# Unable to click a drop down button in selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
<div class="select-wrapper initialized">
  <span class="caret">▼</span>
  <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-56a6924e-42d9-1f78-1b82-fe2c1cbdfbdd" value="R3PORTS, INC">
```

and my code is :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.select-wrapper.initialized")).click();
```

My error is :

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point
>   (210, 30). Other element would receive the click: ...

Comment: <div class="select-wrapper initialized">
  <span class="caret">▼</span>
  <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-56a6924e-42d9-1f78-1b82-fe2c1cbdfbdd" value="R3PORTS, INC">

Comment: do you have to manually interact while selecting the drop down ?